# tr background change with nth-child changes thead and tfoot as well

Tags: css

I am trying to add different colors for `tr`s in my table.

I am trying to using `nth-child(odd)` and `nth-child(even)` but the color in my `thead` and `tfoot` change as well.

Please help.

Comment: Please share the whole snippet with us on plunkr or jsFiddle

Comment: Do not use `nth-child` property because you will have some compatibility issues on IE. Try setting classes to each element.

Comment: so what else that you recommand ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best is probably to add `tbody` explicitly to your structure, e.g.:

```css
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: pink; }
tbody tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: lime; }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead><tr><th>Header</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>row 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 4</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot><tr><td>Footer</td></tr></tfoot>
</table>
```

Note that the CSS [will work](http://jsfiddle.net/RNDDc/) in modern browsers *even* if you omit the `tbody` in your html (at least for this context, the browser "*assumes*" the `tbody` to exist and thus selects rows that are in that body).

Answer (score 0):

Exclude `thead` and `tfoot` by specifying the style for `tr`s that ar only in the body of the table as:

```
tbody tr:nth-child(...){
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the same code that you are using for `thead` and `tfoot` you can write like this

`thead, tfoot{background-color:transparent !important;}`